# Biopython Packages

Tags: python, numpy, bioinformatics, biopython, python-packaging

I installed Bio and updated it, but I got this error again.

```
>>> from Bio.SubsMat import MatrixInfo

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Bio.SubsMat'
```

I deleted and reinstalled it several times, but the problem was not solved.

Comment: Maybe you installed with a *pip* that is not connected to the Python interpreter you are using: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Comment: from Bio.Align import substitution_matrices / matrix = substitution_matrices.load("BLOSUM62")

Answer (score 0):

`Bio.SubsMat` has been deprecated for a while now. Which inherently means that the `MatrixInfo` method is also deprecated. Reading the notes for [Biopython 1.75 (from Nov 2019)](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/8d9d20d09c6ee2a672c8477e890f0ab4e9e48825/NEWS.rst#6-november-2019-biopython-175), it states:

> A new module substitution_matrices was added to Bio.Align, which includes an Array class that can be used as a substitution matrix. As
> the Array class is a subclass of a numpy array, mathematical
> operations can be applied to it directly, and C code that makes use of
> substitution matrices can directly access the numerical values stored
> in the substitution matrices. This module is intended as a replacement
> of Bio.SubsMat, which is currently unmaintained.

Currently it does not appear that the `SubsMat` submodule is installed when you install Biopython. Thus, you get your error! To fix this, try to use the substitution_matrices module in `Bio.Align`. If there is no alternative for the `MatrixInfo` method, you can always install and **older version** of `biopython` that includes it. You'd first have to remove your version of biopython:

```
pip uninstall biopython
```

Then install the older version of biopython

```
pip install biopython==1.76
```

Biopython 1.76 is known to still include the `Bio.SubsMat.MatrixInfo` module. You can verify by looking at the [documentation](https://biopython.org/docs/1.76/api/Bio.SubsMat.MatrixInfo.html) for 1.76.

Answer (score 0):

With Biopython above 1.76 I needed 'BLOSUM62' matrix to run :

`alns = pairwise2.align.globaldx(sample_seq, ref_seq, matrix)`

imported with `from Bio import pairwise2`

for the `matrix` kwyword I used :

```
from Bio.Align import substitution_matrices

matrix = substitution_matrices.load("BLOSUM62")
```

matrices are in `Bio/Align/substitution_matrices/data`

not sure are the same matrices you are asking about